# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.item.txt')

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, react-native

So when I run my app I am getting the error message that says

undefine is not an object (evaluating 'props.item.txt')

Says it is happening in ToDoEdit.js 73:22

Which is the line

```
{props.item.txt || 'New Item'}
```

ToDoEdit.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet,
  Navigator,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native'
var styles = require('../styles')
import InputForm from './InputForm'
var t = require('tcomb-form-native')
let Form = t.form.Form

var ToDo = t.struct({txt: t.Str, complete: t.Bool});

var options = {
  fields: {
    txt: {
      label: 'To-Do Item',
      placeholder: 'enter a to do item here',
      autoFocus: true
    }
  }
};

export default class ToDoEdit extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    //this.onUpdate = this.onUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        navigator={this.props.navigator}
        navigationBar={
          <Navigator.NavigationBar style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)'}}
              routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper(this.props)} />
        } />
    )
  }

  renderScene=(route, navigator) => {
    return(
      <InputForm
        item={this.props.item}
        id={this.props.id}
        onUpdate={this.props.onUpdate}/>
    );
  }
}

var NavigationBarRouteMapper = props => ({
  LeftButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}
          onPress={() => navigator.parentNavigator.pop()}>
        <Text style={styles.back}>
          {"<"}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  },
  RightButton(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return null;
  },
  Title(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={styles.pageTitle}>
          {props.item.txt || 'New Item'}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
})

module.exports = ToDoEdit;
```

So question is, how do I fix this?

--------------------------------------FIXED-------------------------------------

So the issue wasn't that section of code, the problem was with the index.android.js file that was provided to perform this task. We were given an out of date version of the file.

Comment: Well, obviously either `props` or `props.item` is `undefined`. So you need to look at why that is. Use the debugger built into your browser.

Answer (score 2):

If both `item` *and* `txt` may be optional (or even `props` itself), you need to defend against that.

If just `item` and `txt` are the optional ones:

```
{props.item && props.item.txt || 'New item'}
```

is sufficient. If you're unsure about `props`, add it in:

```
{props && props.item && props.item.txt || 'New item'}
```

Example of that first one:

```js
const Example = props => (
  <div>{props.item && props.item.txt || 'New item'}</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Example />
    <Example item={{}} />
    <Example item={{txt: "Item Text"}} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I will look at this, but I did find a fix as well that wasn't in the file. I corrected the post to explain what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use

```
{props.item.txt || 'New Item'}
```

Since item or txt may not exist, so the || part won't run since there will be an error before that. You would need something like this instead:

```
{(props.item && props.item.txt) ? props.item.txt : 'New Item'}
```